# Inkscape on Windows 7 fails to start

Tags: windows-7, inkscape

I have been using Inkscape on my PC for a while and it has always run fine, but suddenly it won't start. Now, when I try to run Inkscape, I get the following error message:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing it and still get the same message. What else can I try?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Seems to be a long-running problem, [there's an open bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/453931) dating back to 2009. Some of the comments there report that restarting the computer solved the problem, other say it only happened when Firefox was also opened.

Comment: ok,"try turning it off and on again" seemed to work... weird

Comment: @Michael: AFAIK Inkscape is a native Win32 program that doesn't use .Net at all.

Comment: @Robert: somehow, I thougt of paint .NET, nvm, I am confused :D

Comment: @Kirstin you might consider posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Many people have reported similar issues, in most cases it would appear to be a conflict with another piece of software.

This means you'll have to think what you installed around the same time.

It appears others have had issues (and had to uninstall)

Adobe Dreamweaver
Scribus
Ghostscript
(this list is not complete)

For some people the fix was Windows Updates, others was a different build (download the latest version), for some a reinstall (although that doesn't work for you) and for some, it's just started to work again with no way to diagnose cause or resolution!

One person found a fix (which helped many others), they wrote

> Then I replaced liblcms-1.dll with the one found at
>   http://cue.yellowmagic.info/softwares/separate-plus/index.html and it
>   now works. I noticed when I attached the MS debugger that there was a
>   little warning that it did not load this dll at the default location,
>   so some other install/security fix may have changed this and
>   indirectly caused the problem.

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/453931)